# Trying to create a txt file but says cannot open file

Tags: c, file, text, null

Very new to programming. I am trying to create a txt file that asks the user for a file name and then text for the file. At first I got an error about a null so I put an if statement and it seems like the code cannot open the file with that name. Tried to do some research and ended up making some changes but still resulted in the same error.

```
include <stdio.h>;
include <stdlib.h>;

int main()

{

    char *fileName[100];
    char inputText[100];


    printf("What is the .txt file name? \n");
    scanf_s("%123s", &fileName);

    strcat(fileName, ".txt");

    FILE *textFile;

    textFile = fopen_s(&textFile, fileName, "w");

    if (textFile != 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot get file");
        return -1;
    }


    printf("What should be written in the text file? \n");
    scanf_s("%123s", &inputText);


    fprintf(textFile, "%s", inputText);


    fclose(textFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code. I recommend you to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/507/files-and-i-o-streams/3468/open-and-write-to-file#t=201607270249425731337

Comment: You create *an array of 100 pointers to char* with `char *fileName[100];`, `char fileName[100] = "";` is sufficient.

Comment: The first problem is that `scanf_s()` requires an explicit length argument for the string variable and you've not supplied it.  You need `if (scanf_s("%99s", fileName, sizeof(fileName)) != 1) { …report error and do not continue… }`, but you also need to fix the type to `char fileName[100];` (100 characters, not 100 character pointers).  The problems continue after that…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing you can do in learning C is to -- *slow down.* There is a lot to learn and you have to take it one step at a time. There is no use in guessing, compiling, seeing if anything changes, changing something else and (repeat). *Look it up.*

That said, you are interested in basic input/output to/from `stdin`/`stdout` and to a file opened for *writing*. It is unclear whether you are working on windows with `scanf_s` or using the non `_s` version as they are mixed and matched below. Regardless, the primary difference there will be the required parameters.

In C, you declare the arrays to hold your *filename* and *inputtext* to hold `100` characters. When working with strings, each string requires a *nul-terminating* character at the end (`'\0'`... or just `0`, numerically the same). That means you can store a *maximum* of `99` characters `+1` *nul-terminating* character in either `filename` or `inputtext` (side note: C generally avoids mixed-case variable names in favor of all lower-case, but that is up to you)

To protect against writing beyond the end of your `filename` or `inputtext`, you need to insure that you *limit* the number of characters you attempt to store in either. You do that with the *field-width* option to the *format specifier*. e.g.,

```
scanf ("%99s", inputtext);
```

or for the windows `_s` version:

```
scanf_s ("%99s", inputtext, 100u);
```

However, using a format specifier of `"%99s"` does not allow the input to include *whitespace* as the `%s` *format specifier* will read up to the first *whitespace* or *newline*. Second, it does NOT read (or in anyway handle) the `'\n'` at the end of user-input generated as the result of pressing <kbd>[Enter]</kbd>. This will cause problems if your next input is character input as `scanf` will happily accept `'\n'` as the next character to be read. Now `%s` will skip leading whitespace (`'\n'` being whitespace) should not present a problem, but this is the level of thought process you must go through in forming something as simple as your `scanf` *format string*.

Get in the habit of accounting for *all characters* in the input stream every time. That way you are not caught off-guard with some error you cannot explain.

To allow your input to contain whitespace, you can use a *character class* format specifier for `scanf`. For instance you could use `"%99[^\n]"` as the format string. However the character class does not automatically ignore leading whitespace, but you can provide that flexibility by leaving a `space` before the `%` beginning the format specifier, e.g. `" %99[^\n]"`. It is important. (it is also why `fgets` or POSIX `getline` are generally preferred over `scanf` for handling user-input.

Now how do you handle the `'\n'` you left in the input buffer (e.g. `stdin` here)? In addition to leaving the `space`, you can make use of the *assignment suppression operator* within the format string. `" %99[^\n]%*c"` The `%*c` is a format specifier for reading a character `%c`, but by including the `'*'` (assignment suppression operator), you tell `scanf` to *read and discard* the character.

It is not enough to simply provide the correct *format specifier* when taking user-input. You must *VALIDATE* that you have actually received the input you expect. With any of the input routines, that, at minimum, means checking the return for `scanf` (or `fgets` or `getline`, etc..). For `scanf`, the return is the  "*match count*", which is the *number of successful conversions performed according the the format string*. e.g. the `%s` (or `%[^\n]`) constitute a request for a single conversion. (any conversion associated with the assignment suppression operator is NOT included in the match count) So your anticipated return is the number of conversions in your format string. Putting that together, you could handle your `inputtext` with:

```
    printf ("What should be written in the text file? "); /* prompt */
    /* validate user input -- limit to 99 chars (+1 for nul char)  */
    if (scanf (" %99[^\n]%*c", inputtext) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (inputtext).\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Wouldn't the same thing also work for `filename`? Answer: **No.** Why? You plan on appending `".txt"` to `filename` after entered by the user, right? How many characters are in `".txt"`? Answer: `4` (you will only have `1` *nul-terminating* char for the combined string). So what must you limit `filename` to? `" %95[^\n]%*c"`

To do file I/O, you have several choices. By far the *fstream* buffered I/O functions are the most common for basic text I/O. In order to read from, or write to, a file, you must first open a `FILE` stream. You do that by declaring a `FILE *pointer` and then calling `fopen` and then checking the return (the value of `pointer`) to validate your file was successfully opened. The same rules, format specifiers, etc.. apply to reading/writing to a file (on disk), just as they do to writing to `stdin` or `stdout` as all are simply files from C's perspective.

With that in mind, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXC = 100 };

int main (void) {

    /* declare and initialize variables */
    char filename[MAXC] = "", inputtext[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    printf ("What is the .txt file name? ");    /* prompt */

    /* validate user input -- limit to 95 chars */
    if (scanf (" %95[^\n]%*c", filename) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (filename).\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcat (filename, ".txt");  /* +4 chars = 99 chars */

    /* open file/validate file open for reading */
    if (!(fp = fopen (filename, "w"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("What should be written in the text file? "); /* prompt */
    /* validate user input -- limit to 99 chars (+1 for nul char)  */
    if (scanf (" %99[^\n]%*c", inputtext) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (inputtext).\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* output status to stdout & inputtext to fp */
    printf ("\nwriting to '%s'\n%s\n", filename, inputtext);
    fprintf (fp, "%s\n", inputtext);

    if (fclose (fp))    /* close file - validate stream close */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: on file stream close.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** after *writing* to a file, it is important to check the return of `fclose` to insure a stream error did not occur during the write. (for closing streams you read from, that concern isn't there)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inputtext
What is the .txt file name? dat/inputtext
What should be written in the text file? A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

writing to 'dat/inputtext.txt'
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Check the file contents:

```
$ cat dat/inputtext.txt
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Look the code over and let me know if you have any questions *regarding any character* in the code. Everyone needs a little help getting started, and the most important thing I can convey is to slow down and understand every character you code, read and understand your compiler warnings (fix every one), and if you are not sure about what you are doing, look it up. Either `man function` on Linux/Unix, or search MSDN for windows (e.g. [**scanf_s,...**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)). They tell you in reasonably clear term what type and requirements there are for every parameter to every function (and a lot provide examples).

Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation fopen_s takes an argument of form FILE** rather than FILE*. It also returns an error code rather than the file handle, which is not the return value of the function. So what you've done in this code is overwritten your file handle with some irrelevant integer. If you store your error code in a different variable it should resolve that issue.

More information on fopen_s can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx

Comment: @RetiredNinja Damn. My Bad. Corrected.